# SXA Page Design vs Page Standard Values vs Page Branch Template

Tags: best-practices, templates, sxa, presentation

Sitecore historically had two options for building reusable page design:

1. Page Standard Values
2. Branch Template

Both these options allow to build composition of visual components and later build pages reusing that design.

SXA has its own implementation called `Page Design`:

> In SXA, you work with reusable pieces of content and layout. A page
>   design in SXA is a group of partial layouts that make up the design of
>   a webpage.
>
> For example, you may need a reusable page structure for a blog page.
>   By creating a page design for a blog, you can create a basic template
>   that content authors can use to create content without having to worry
>   about the design of the page.

What are the benefits of `SXA Page Designs` and when should I use each option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With **Sitecore Experience Accelerator** you can forget about previous methods, however, there is nothing that will block you from using them.

**Before - NO SXA**:

- you had to decide how your page will look like before you entered content (because the presentation was stored either on SV or somewhere inside different branches)
- you couldn't easily switch your presentation once you created your item with predefined presentation details. Option for doing that could be changing the template to use a different one with different presentation or manipulate presentation manually. Not so comfortable if we are talking about thousands of pages.

**Now - SXA:**

With **SXA** you can use the same approach, however, what makes it special is the fact that you can treat your items like a data storage and define presentation somewhere else.

Why is it cool?

Because when you've got your data and presentation decoupled you can easily change presentation details any time you want (there is so called design to template mapping).

[image]

Notice that all you need to do is to change the value of a single drop down to change the Design of all pages under your site.

Of course, you are not forced to define presentation details in one place and data in another. Page designs are sort of set of renderings injected onto your page but are not there in reality. You are able to add your additional renderings even that and page will render merged content at the end.

Here are key points:

**Advantages:**

- flexibility - you can easily switch presentation details without touching templates
- maintainability - you can build partial designs like normal pages (open Experience Editor and drop renderings), you couldn't manipulate presentation details using previous approaches
- hierarchy - data templates definition are stored under templates, where designers (presentation designers) should no go to, that's why presentation can be created on so-called **Partial Designs**, I think it is pretty important to keep things secure.
- re-usability - as you probably know **page designs** are build from **partial designs**. In this case, you can reuse existing presentation parts. Let's say you define single header  **partial design** and then use it on different designs where content part or footer is different.

Comment: Would it still be preferred to also create branch templates in some cases if you have multiple usages of a page template that are used by different page type variations and you want to set default components with mock datasources?

Comment: This link answers my question, they go hand in hand: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/use-a-page-branch-574715.html